# Get music from subsonic to run in headless MPD

Tags: mpd, mediaplayer

I share a subsonic server with several colleagues, together we have around 22k songs up there. Now I want to set up a MPD on something like a raspberry pi to listen to the music from subsonic. I want to use MPD because I can control it wireless via my smartphone or something similar.

The problem is that I do not know how to connect the subsonic with the MPD. I can export playlists from subsonic but the URLs are relative to the server's filesystem, so no chance here.

Do you have any ideas? The subsonic is set, MPD not. Maybe there is something similar which I can use.

Comment: These seem like good leads: http://forum.subsonic.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8388 & https://fruit.je/mpd-rtp

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Mopidy](https://www.mopidy.com/) a MPD implementation with [a subsonic plugin](https://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/ext/backends/#mopidy-subsonic).
I use it at home, it's simple to install and it works well.